# JQuery Resize Not Working When Loading

Tags: jquery, resize, positioning, center

I have a div like this:

```
<div class="first">
<img src="image/image1.gif" style="width:30%;display:inline-block"/> 
<img src="image/image2.gif" style="width:30%;display:inline-block"/> 
<img src="image/image3.gif" style="width:30%;display:inline-block"/>
<br />testing<br /><br />がらんどう
</div>
```

I want it to *vertically center and resizable* so I use standard JQuery code:

```
$(window).resize(function(){

$('.first').css({
    position:'absolute',
    top: ($(window).height() - $('.first').outerHeight())/2
});
});

$(window).resize();
```

The css for the div is like this:

```
.first
{
position:absolute;
top:50%;
}
```

**The problem is:**
The div is not vertically centralized upon loading, but when u resize the window, it will be centralized..

Can you guys help me figure out? Thanks!!

Comment: Is your code inside the `$(document).ready()` handler?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/HADew/2/

Comment: @DipeshParmar Yes yours works because your fiddle is setup to run `onLoad`. That's the thing. Except real code needs an event, not some fiddle setup

Comment: @Ian yes that what i was trying to say OP..but did not added text because all of the answer say for me....

Comment: I think there is some confuse with my naming. I change .first to this and it works. Thanks guys :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have your `.resize()` call inside of `$(document).ready()`, right? Otherwise, none or many elements won't be ready/available. You probably want:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(window).resize(function(){
        $(".first").css({
            position:'absolute',
            top: function () {
                return ($(window).height() - $(this).outerHeight())/2;
            }
        });
    });
    $(window).resize();
});
```

Also, you want to use `$(this).outerHeight()` instead of `$('.first').outerHeight()`

Since some browsers fire `resize` very often during resizing (some only fire it at the end of a resize), it might be "better" to cache the jQuery `window` object:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var $window = $(window);
    $window.resize(function(){
        $('.first').css({
            position:'absolute',
            top: function () {
                return ($window.height() - $(this).outerHeight())/2;
            }
        });
    });
    $window.resize();
});
```

Comment: my error was that I was using `$(document).resize(` instead of `$(window).resize(` but your answer show me that =P +1

Answer (score 0):

It seems you want to position your'.first' div in the center of window.
If thats it you don't actually need resize event. This will work

```
$(function () {
    var first = $('.first');
    first.css({
        'margin-top': -first.height();
    });
});
```

If you want it on center of window. use CSS

.first {

```
position: fixed,
top: 50 %
```

}

If you want it center of document or other offset parent give `position:absolute`.
Same you can do for left if you want.

Even if you know size of '.first' div you can directly give margin-top (=-height/2) property on css. than you dont need javascript code for this.

If you want to do it with top position than keep your resize handler inside document.ready handler

```
$(function(){   
    var first = $('.first');
    $(window).resize(function(){ 
       first.css({
          top: ($(window).height() - first.outerHeight(true)) / 2
       });
    }).resize();  
})
```